How to re-use rules in GitLab CI/CD without copying them
Here is an example (my example has separate files for no particular reason other than that I am mirroring a real world setup which uses multiple files).
.gitlab-ci.yml:
include:
  - local: 'ci-cd/build.yml'
  - local: 'ci-cd/deploy.yml'

stages:
  - Initialize
  - Build
  - Deploy

variables:
  RUN_BUILDS: "true"
  DEPLOY:
    value: "false"
    description: "Deploy ?"

Initialize stuff:
  stage: Initialize
  script:
    - echo "Initialized"

build.yml:
Build Job:
  stage: Build
  script:
    - echo "Building.... :)"
    - mkdir bin
    - cat project/hugabuga.txt >> bin/output.txt
    - echo -e "\nBuilding done!" >> bin/output.txt
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - bin/**/*
    expire_in: 1h
  rules:
    - if: '$RUN_BUILDS == "true"'
      changes:
        - project/**/*
    - if: '$DEPLOY == "true" || $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ "/deploy/"'

deploy.yml:
Deploy Job:
  needs: ["Build Job"]
  before_script:
    - echo "Deploying..."
  script:
    - cat bin/output.txt
    - echo $DEPLOY_LOCAL
    - echo $DEPLOY
  rules:
    - if: '$DEPLOY == "true" || $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ "/deploy/"'

As you can see, the rule - if: '$DEPLOY == "true" || $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ "/deploy/"' is repeated in both jobs. Ideally I want this one defined only once and re-used in both. Is this possible?
I cannot have a common job that both inherit because the build job needs some additional rules which the deploy job should not have.
To summarize the scenario I want:

The build job is triggered when there are changes in the project/**/* path and RUN_BUILDS is true.
Independently, the build job should also be triggered if the DEPLOY variable is manually set to true (by running a manual pipeline) or if the commit message matches a specific regex
As with the build job, I want the deploy job to trigger if the conditions in the last bullet are filled but I don't want a deploy job created if only changes are detected (and RUN_BUILDS is true). A deploy job needs either the matching commit message or manual DEPLOY flag to true
In short, a deploy job is not always created when a build job is (if only due to changes)

How to re-use a single rule and append it to another set of rules? Preferably with readable YAML.
Edit - Additional information
So I forgot to mention the fact that I did get this working in principle using the, from the comments, suggested !reference keyword of GitLab YAML. However, as in the real world pipeline we have multiple deploy jobs in that file which all share similar triggers and rules etc. I tried to be a bit more clever - which eventually caused my solution to not work.
What did work is basically swapping the last line of the build job's rules section with - !reference ["Deploy Job", "rules"]. This gives me the exact behaviour I want. Though, I wanted also to use a "base" deploy job which could be shared between other deploy jobs. Each deploy job would have their own "global" DEPLOY_something variable which could be set in a manual pipeline. They would also all have their own regex patterns. This meant that the rules could not directly reference the global DEPLOY_something (DEPLOY in my example) variable, but had to define some local variable to be overridden on a per-job basis. So this is basically what I tried in my deploy.yml:
.deploy-base:
  stage: Deploy
  variables:
    DEPLOY_LOCAL: "false"
    MSG_PATTERN: /default/ 
  rules:
    - if: $DEPLOY_LOCAL == "true" || $CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ $MSG_PATTERN   

Deploy Job: 
  extends: .deploy-base
  variables:
    DEPLOY_LOCAL: $DEPLOY
    MSG_PATTERN: /deploy/ 
  needs: ["Build Job"]
  before_script:
    - echo "Deploying..."
  script:
    - cat bin/output.txt
    - echo $DEPLOY_LOCAL
    - echo $DEPLOY

The idea is that each Deploy job that would inherit the base just overrides the variables with their respective patterns and global manual variables and I would expect the rules to reflect that. Additionally, I then of course need to add the setting of variables in the Build job too as the rules now contain un-overridden variables from the perspective of the build job. So I simply added the line variables: !reference ["Deploy Job", "variables"] to my Build job which should mirror the setting of variables from the deploy job.
This actually almost works, but not quite. It works for the pattern match, if I commit using "deploy" as commit message, both jobs are correctly created. However, if my last commit message was something else, and I run a manual pipeline where I set DEPLOY = true it oddly enough only creates the build job but not the deploy job. To make things even more confusing, if I comment out the - if '$RUN_BUILDS... + changes rule in the build job, and try again using manual pipeline DEPLOY = true, neither job is created! This leads me to believe that the manual pipeline variable passing through the overridden variables and inherited job actually does not work at all, and for some reason the additional rule in the Build job causes it to somehow work... I don't know really, it has me so baffled.
Any ideas?

Have you read https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_rules.html#reuse-rules-in-different-jobs it seems to describe what you have

Yes, I actually did use !reference and got it working that way, though I tried to further be even more clever which caused the end result to not work. I will update my post with info
